# Implementing a memoization table with a map templated on a pair of int, int and int

Tags: c++, dictionary, memoization

I have implemented a recursive algorithm, to improve the performance I want to add a memoization table. The most natural structure for my problem would be

```
map<pair<int,int>,int> lookup_table;
```

and the recursive algorithm that I use is

```
int max_sum_path(int maximum_rows,vector<vector<int> >& matrix,int row_index,int colm_index)
{
  if(row_index >= maximum_rows || colm_index > row_index)
  {
    //we have reached a cell outside the Triangular Matrix
    return 0;
  }
  else if(lookup_table.find(row_index,colm_index) != lookup_table.end())
  {
    //the memoization step to avoid repeated calculations and make recursion more efficient
    return lookup_table[row_index,colm_index];
  }
  else
  {
    lookup_table[row_index,colm_index] = matrix[row_index][colm_index] + max(max_sum_path(maximum_rows,matrix,row_index+1,colm_index), max_sum_path(maximum_rows,matrix,row_index+1,colm_index+1));
    return lookup_table[row_index,colm_index];
  }
}
```

This throws a tonne of compiler errors. I'm not sure if the syntax is correct.
Should I be using a string buffer to create a string and then use it instead of the pair?

Here are the compiler errors:

```
sums_triangle.cpp: In function ‘int max_sum_path(int, std::vector<std::vector<int> >&, int, int)’:
sums_triangle.cpp:50:49: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int>::find(int&, int&)’
sums_triangle.cpp:50:49: note: candidates are:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_map.h:736:7: note: std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::find(const key_type&) [with _Key = std::pair<int, int>, _Tp = int, _Compare = std::less<std::pair<int, int> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, int> >, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, int> >, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = std::pair<int, int>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_map.h:736:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_map.h:751:7: note: std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::find(const key_type&) const [with _Key = std::pair<int, int>, _Tp = int, _Compare = std::less<std::pair<int, int> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, int> >, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, int> >, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = std::pair<int, int>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_map.h:751:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
sums_triangle.cpp:53:35: warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
sums_triangle.cpp:53:45: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘lookup_table[(0, colm_index)]’
sums_triangle.cpp:53:45: note: candidate is:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_map.h:445:7: note: std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = std::pair<int, int>, _Tp = int, _Compare = std::less<std::pair<int, int> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, int> >, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = int, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = std::pair<int, int>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_map.h:445:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const key_type& {aka const std::pair<int, int>&}’
sums_triangle.cpp:57:28: warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
sums_triangle.cpp:57:38: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘lookup_table[(0, colm_index)]’
sums_triangle.cpp:57:38: note: candidate is:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_map.h:445:7: note: std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = std::pair<int, int>, _Tp = int, _Compare = std::less<std::pair<int, int> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, int> >, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = int, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = std::pair<int, int>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_map.h:445:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const key_type& {aka const std::pair<int, int>&}’
sums_triangle.cpp:58:35: warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
sums_triangle.cpp:58:45: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘lookup_table[(0, colm_index)]’
sums_triangle.cpp:58:45: note: candidate is:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_map.h:445:7: note: std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = std::pair<int, int>, _Tp = int, _Compare = std::less<std::pair<int, int> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, int> >, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = int, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = std::pair<int, int>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_map.h:445:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const key_type& {aka const std::pair<int, int>&}’
sums_triangle.cpp:60:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Just to be clear, I'm not sure if the syntax is correct. I want to know how I can use a pair as the key for a map.

Extra Info:
I had asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412185/right-way-of-passing-a-2d-vector-as-an-argument-to-a-function-in-c) question earlier. I'm optimizing it now. Feel free to suggest a different structure for the memoization table.

Comment: -1 for not posting the errors along with code. Don't make us compile your code to see the error.

Comment: Have you got a `using std::map; using std::vector; ...` or `using namespace std;` somewhere in the code?

Comment: @nikhil: -1 removed, since now you've posted errors as well.

Comment: This looks like it's also a Project Euler problem. You should not need recursion at all if you want to make it fast. Hint: don't start from the top, start from the bottom.

Comment: @UncleBens : Got this working. Give me a little more to work with, would love to make it faster.

Comment: The task is solvable with a purely linear algorithm (with pen and paper for reasonable small amount of lines), starting from the bottom (second row from the bottom). You might want to cross out each number in all rows except last and write a new number in its place exactly once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this,

```
lookup_table.find(row_index,colm_index) //incorrect - your code
```

write this,

```
lookup_table.find(std::make_pair(row_index,colm_index)) //correct - my code
```

Similarly see these as well,

```
lookup_table[row_index,colm_index];  //incorrect  - your code
lookup_table[std::make_pair(row_index,colm_index)]; //correct - my code
```

#### Explanation:

Since `lookup_table` is `std::map<std::pair<int,int>,int>`, its key type is `std::pair<int,int>`, so the index to `lookup_table` has to be its key, when you use `[]` operator.

`std::make_pair` is a utility function which returns an object of type `std::pair<int,int>` if both arguments to `std::make_pair` are `int`.  Instead of writing, `std::make_pair`, you can use `std::pair<int,int>(row_index,colm_index)` but this looks cumbersome, that is why `std::make_pair` is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not python.
You can't use this syntax:

```
lookup_table[row_index,colm_index]
```

You need do use make_pair() to create the pair:

```
lookup_table[std::make_pair(row_index,colm_index)]
```

Other than that, you probably should use the iterator returned from map.find() to return your memoized result. As it stands now, you are making the lookup twice.

Comment: +1 for the python analogy. 
Some of the syntax there is simply beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

Store the `row_index` and `colm_index` in a `std::pair`:

```
pair<int, int> map_key_value = std::make_pair(row_index, colm_index);
```

Then use `map_key_value` in `lookup_table.find()` and `lookup_table[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access `map<pair<int,int>,int>` using `lookup_table[row_index,colm_index]` and `find(row_index,colm_index)`. To access it, you have to create a pair of two ints.